# SPContext current is always null

Tags: sharepoint-server, wcf, learning-kit

We are using Sharepoint learning kit to deliver eLearning course to our employees.

Sharepoint learning kit (SLK) .wsp is deployed to  a site collection.

I have created a seperate .net WCF upload service which uploads document to Site document library and uses one of the API from SLK to create an assignment.

I have copied the dll from SLK's build and put in a folder inside upload service, from where the dll are referenced to SLK in my upload service

Since uploding document does not have dependency on SLK API, it works fine.

The problem started when i call a method from SLK API where it fail to GET SPcontext

Sharepoint Site URL  : http://wingtipserver:28000/

Upload Service URL   : http://wingtipserver:26898/uploadService.svc

can anyone point me in right direction to resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

You only have an SPContext if your code is executed inside SharePoint. Instead you can create your own instances of SPSite etc by giving the URL of the SharePoint Site as parameter.

Comment: Hi Gwny, Inside Sharepoint means within the site collection or same server ? i have hosted my .net Service in the same server different port.

Answer (score 0):

Deploying a webservice in IIS doesn't mean it runs under SharePoint context. What you should do is deploy the service to into SharePoint ISAPI folder as explained in this article

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2010/07/16/writing-and-hosting-a-web-service-in-the-sharepoint-2010-demo-virtual-machine.aspx

Now you will be getting the `SPContext`. If you access the URL via SharePoint URL

http://site/_vti_bin/service.asmx - Where service.asmx is your custom service and you will get `SPContext` as null because of Redirection. In such cases you should create the required SharePoint objects as explained in this thread

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fc7f22df-3b10-4084-a63f-f2ef2b15e168/sharepoint2010-custom-webservice-spcontext